# Query doesn't retrun true value in iif ms-access sql

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access

I want to get `RollNo` if it is present when certain conditions meet otherwise it should return **-1**. But in my case it is returning `RollNo` when its present, otherwise it returns **nothing**.

SQL is under:-

```
SELECT iif(isnull(RollNo),-1,RollNo) from students where SName = "sf" and FName= "da" and 
DOB=#7/16/2020# and ClassID = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm . . . If you always want to return exactly one row, then I would suggest aggregation:

```
SELECT NZ(MAX(RollNo), -1)
FROM students 
WHERE SName = "sf" and FName= "da" and DOB=#7/16/2020# and ClassID = 0;
```

If nothing matches the `WHERE` clause, then `MAX(RollNo)` returns `NULL` -- which is converted to a `-1` by `NZ()`.

Comment: This works in access. But I have to get this in C# code. `nz` not works in c#

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan Would this work: `SELECT IIF(ISNULL(MAX(RollNo)), -1, MAX(RollNo)` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this is working. I have checked this query.

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan . . . Can you determine which part of the query is not working?  Perhaps `COALESCE()` works.  `NZ()` is definitely part of MS Access:  https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/nz.php.

Comment: `nz` works when queried inside access. It does not work in C# code.

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan . . . You can replace it with `IIF(MAX(RollNo) IS NULL, MAX(RollNo), -1)`.

Answer (score 0):

This returns exactly one row with field `RollNo`.

```
SELECT iif(isnull(max(RollNo)),-1,max(RollNo)) from students where SName = "sf" and
 FName= "da" and DOB=#7/16/2020# and ClassID = 0
```

if the conditions in where clause meet it return `RollNo` otherwise return `-1`

Comment: Interesting `ISNULL` (a VBA method) worked with an ODCB/OLEDB Access connection. Better to use SQL's `IS NULL` expression.

Comment: I don't know but this working. `IS NULL` expression worked also.